# Azure Notification Hub bulk registration using REST API

Tags: python, rest, azure, azure-notificationhub

Our service send Push Notification to user via admin site based on Django, 
using **Azure Notification Hub REST API**.

The thing is, I want to add tags to large number of users and make **bulk registration** to Notification Hub.

here is my python trial code for **single** registration

```
def register_tag(xml_data):
    headers = {"Content-type": "application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8",
               "Authorization": *******,
               "x-ms-version": "2015-01"}

    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("MyNameSpace.servicebus.windows.net")
    conn.request("POST", '/MyNotificationHub/registrations/?api-version=2015-01', xml_data, headers)
    resp = conn.getresponse()
    return resp
```

and this is Sample xml data using ElementTree for iOS device registration

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, dump
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

def push_register_gen_xml(request):
    # CREATE XML String
    entry = Element("entry")
    entry.attrib["xmlns"] = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"

    content = Element("content")
    content.attrib["type"] = "application/xml"

    AppleRegistrationDescription = Element("AppleRegistrationDescription")
    AppleRegistrationDescription.attrib["xmlns:i"] = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    AppleRegistrationDescription.attrib["xmlns"] = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect"

    entry.append(content)
    content.append(AppleRegistrationDescription)
    SubElement(AppleRegistrationDescription, "Tags").text = "Sample Tag"
    SubElement(AppleRegistrationDescription, "DeviceToken").text = "One Device Token"

    # ADD xml declareation
    et = ET.tostring(entry).decode("utf-8")
    xml_declare = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
    body = xml_declare + et

    return body
```

I found this for Export and Modify Registrations in Bulk > https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790624.aspx. but It's not REST API...

thanks for reading...:D

Comment: What is your question? If you just want to do the operations for `Export and Modify Registrations`, I think you can refer to the reference [`REST API Methods`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495827.aspx) for NotificationHubs to find the methods you want, such as `Create or update Registration` or `Read all Registrations`. Please improve your description for your question.

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT  I saw this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223265.aspx 
but it shows just one entry. I want to know how to create multiple entry in one POST request... thank you.